# Entity Framework - How To Handle Batch SaveChanges Failure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, quickbooks

In my C# program I am using Entity Framework to synchronize a local SQL Server database with QuickBooks data. Getting the data from QuickBooks does not seem to have any issues. However I am running into a stumbling block when doing batch commits of entities.

Currently I am building up the `DataContext` with a configurable number of entities and then committing the entities in batch. So far the batch has not failed, but what if it does? My idea to combat this would be to iterate over the batch and submit each entity one at a time and then log the one(s) that is/are causing the commit failure.

However I do not see a way to do this with the data context since it appears to be an all or nothing matter when using `SaveChanges()`. Is there a way to handle what I am trying to accomplish, or should I be going about dealing with the failures in a completely different way?

Here is the code that I currently have, in case you want to take a look at it:

```
 int itemsCount = 0;
 int itemsSynced = 0;
 int itemsFailed = 0;

 ArrayList exceptions = new ArrayList();

 int batchSliceCount = Properties.Settings.Default.SyncBatchSize; //Getting the max batch size from the settings
 int index = 1; //Index used for keeping track of current batch size on data context
 List<Customer> currentBatch = new List<Customer>(); // List to hold curent batch

 db = new DataContext(DatabaseHelper.GetLocalDatabaseConnectionString());

 foreach (var customer in QBResponse.customers)
 {
     itemsCount++;

     try
     {
         string debugMsg = "Saving Customer with the Following Details....." + Environment.NewLine;
         debugMsg += "ListId: " + customer.CustomerListId + Environment.NewLine;
         debugMsg += "FullName: " + customer.FullName + Environment.NewLine;
         int progressPercentage = (itemsCount * 100) / opResponse.retCount;
         UpdateStatus(Enums.LogLevel.Debug, debugMsg, progressPercentage);

         var dbCustomer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerListId == customer.CustomerListId);

         if (dbCustomer == null)
         {
             // customer.CopyPropertiesFrom(customer, db);
             Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
             newCustomer.CopyCustomer(customer, db);
             newCustomer.AddBy = Enums.OperationUser.SyncOps;
             newCustomer.AddDateTime = DateTime.Now;
             newCustomer.EditedBy = Enums.OperationUser.SyncOps;
             newCustomer.EditedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
             newCustomer.SyncStatus = true;

             db.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
             currentBatch.Add(newCustomer);
         }
         else
         {
             //dbCustomer.CopyPropertiesFrom(customer, db);
             dbCustomer.CopyCustomer(customer, db);
             dbCustomer.EditedBy = Enums.OperationUser.SyncOps;
             dbCustomer.EditedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
             dbCustomer.SyncStatus = true;
             currentBatch.Add(dbCustomer);
         }

         try
         {
             if (index % batchSliceCount == 0 || index == opResponse.customers.Count()) //Time to submit the batch
             {
                 UpdateStatus(Enums.LogLevel.Information, "Saving Batch of " + batchSliceCount + "Customers to Local Database");
                 db.SaveChanges();
                 itemsSynced += currentBatch.Count();
                 currentBatch = new List<Customer>();
                 db.Dispose();
                 db = new DataContext(DatabaseHelper.GetLocalDatabaseConnectionString());
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             string errorMsg = "Error occured submitting batch. Itterating and submitting one at a time. " + Environment.NewLine;
             errorMsg += "Error Was: " + ex.GetBaseException().Message + Environment.NewLine + "Stack Trace: " + ex.GetBaseException().StackTrace;
             UpdateStatus(Enums.LogLevel.Debug, errorMsg, progressPercentage);

             //What to do here? Is there a way to properly iterate over the context and submit a change one at a time? 
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         //Log exception and restart the data context
         db.Dispose();
         db = new DataContext(DatabaseHelper.GetLocalDatabaseConnectionString());
     }

     Thread.Sleep(Properties.Settings.Default.SynchronizationSleepTimer);
     index++;
 }
```

Comment: Tough question for sure, here's what I'd do...  If there was an exception on the SaveChanges I'd try to write the content to a log so that at least the changes were still available.  However, EF is supposed to take care of this right, with it's "Tracking" ability.  I've never had to work with recovery before so I'm just thinking out loud here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the exceptions you want to recover from...

If you are just looking for a way to retry if the connection was interrupted you could use a custom **Execution Strategy** based on [DbExecutionStrategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbexecutionstrategy(v=vs.113).aspx) that retries if specific errors occur as demonstrated in this [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758469/Implementing-Connection-Resiliency-with-Entity-Fra) article.

Comment: I'm aware of using an Execution Strategy to deal with timeouts. I've yet to implement it but it is on the development road map. I'm more concerned with exceptions such as key violations (I.E. The entity batch being committed is being rejected by SQL Server).

Comment: since there is no way retrying could solve key violation errors I would recommend you validate the batch yourself before you try to safe it to the store